# Lost several messages in consumer when consuming message using @KafkaListener

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have 10 topics and send 1000 messages to broker every 5 minutes and I lost several messages sent from the producer using threads when sending messages, and the consumers using @kafkalistener. 
how can I handle this problem? Are there any settings on the wrong producer or consumer? i use 2 broker and consumer group.

i think @KafkaListener cannot listen carefully, example 10 message are coming to 1 topic and the listener just receive 3 messages and 7 messages are lost.

this is my producer

```
public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9095,localhost:9094");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, retries);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, batchSize);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, linger);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, bufferMemory);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, 1);
    return props;
}

public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<String, String>(producerFactory());
}
```

this is my consumer

```
@Bean
public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(concurrency);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(1500);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    return factory;
}

public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
}

public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
    Map<String, Object> propsMap = new HashMap<>();
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9095,localhost:9094");
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, autoCommitInterval);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, sessionTimeout);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_id");
    propsMap.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, autoOffsetReset);
    return propsMap;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some source code on how you produce your messages (incl. the configuration of the producer) and you you consume them. Otherwise all we could do is just guessing.

Comment: please check my update

Comment: Are you flushing the producer for each batch of messages you want to send? If the messages are also missing from console consumer, then the listener isn't the issue, the producer is

Comment: yeah, im flushing every message, and call function callback if message fail when sending to broker. i think its not producer issue, but consumer. Based on my explanation above, if i send 10 messages to one topic, the consumer just read 3 messages and lost 7 messages